# How to draw Deployment diagram when system deployed on cloud server?

Tags: deployment, uml, diagram, deployment-diagram

Deployment diagrams are typically used to visualize the physical hardware and software of a system. So I how can I draw deployment diagram when system is deployed on cloud server. Is there any examples to see me?

Comment: What do you mean by "cloud server"? Do you mean an instance of an OS (e.g. VM on cloud IaaS) such as you might create using in a subscription of Azure, AWS, GCP etc.? A container running on a PaaS Container Platform like GKE? A web site (e.g. an HTTPS web server that someone else hosts)? A specific application in "the cloud" (e.g. SaaS like Salesforce)? All of these can be represented in Deployment Models but I'm not sure what the most appropriate answer would be without more info. Cheers, Mart.

Answer (score 0):

How can you draw something you don't know? You can't really, can you? However, you could just draw a cloud symbol. That "clearly" shows the reader "here is a service where I don't know the details. But that's it. UML allows to use non-standard symbols. So for a cloud based server you can either draw a cloud or a component symbol that has a cloud decoration (icon at the top right corner).

Comment: The OP probably knows more than you'd think. "Cloud" is just a bunch of servers run by someone else, and of course you can engage in those at varying degrees of abstraction from the H/W -- e.g. a VM, Container, App Platform, Web Site and so on. "Cloud" is such a wonderful term, it adds a layer of marketing mystery / mystique to what is essentially just a bunch of servers and software.

Answer (score 0):

There are still parts of a cloud infrastructure that you can outline in a deployment diagram:

- Subnet topology (in Azure, you get that generated from Azure Portal) and Firewall instances
- Stages of your system, such as development / test / quality / production
- Protocols, Ports (e.g. where does SSL terminate)
- Differentiation which artifacts get deployed to which cluster and which type of server (media server / app server / webserver /...)

It really depends on what your audience wants to know.